# Counting and handling php script process running time

Tags: php, drupal, error-handling

I have some code that I know will reach max timeout at some point.

I tried using try-catch to handle this error, but I have just been informed timeouts can't be caught this way.

Is there a way I can catch the error, or count processing time and handle the error just before it reaches timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly mentioned by `iTom`, first you need to figure out, why your code is taking 30 seconds.

If it is expected & you are doing some sort to database updation then in drupal, we have provision to handle this. You need to use **Drupal batch APIs**.

Check here for more details: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/batch/7

> Functions allowing forms processing to be spread out over several page
>   requests, thus ensuring that the processing does not get interrupted
>   because of a PHP timeout, while allowing the user to receive feedback
>   on the progress of the ongoing operations.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum execution time is a PHP Error not a PHP Exception, therefore your error handling code will be unable to catch an exception that doesn't actually exist. The Execution time limit is really a last resort for the PHP Server to kill a function that's basically gone out of control.

You really need to look into why your database code is taking 30~ seconds to execute and resolve the code/database issue. Another (not recommended) option would be to increase the Maximum execution time in PHP to something suitable for your code.

Comment: Thanks, the query to delete nodes is created by the framework, as a part of it's core. Anyway, I only need to do the deleting (and later adding) process once. 

Is there no way to catch time outs?

Comment: Ok, changed the question entirely based on your input

Answer (score 0):

You can echo time() at before and after of function to count processing